# Cannot find command after reboot even though chmod +x was successful?

Tags: centos, redhat, chmod

Dealing with a weird problem on CentOS trying to add the Play! framework to my path. Just earlier I successfully did a `chmod +x play` on Play! and I could run commands.

Then I rebooted and it completely fails. All attempts to retry `chmod` fail. I'm doing this from root user, it has 777 permissions, and belongs to the root group.

```
bash: play: command not found
```

What am I not considering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't enough to just add the directory to `$PATH`; you must make a change to your configuration to add it to `$PATH` on reboot or shell start. Try editing `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Switched from Solaris and just not yet familiar with RHEL/CentOS yet ;) This did it `alias play="/home/usrName/javaApi/play-1.1/play"`

Comment: Aliases is a bad work around if you just wanted it in your $PATH, and Solaris works the same way by the way. See this link for more info on .bashrc and .bash_profile: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html